# Triangle from cartesian coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates, point, cartesian

I'm newbie. I have a class Triangle which receives 3 list  variables with format [x, y]: `a`, `b` and `c`. How can I return the string with the triangle's cartesian points?

```
 class Triangle():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        """
        Constructor for Vec4
        Expects points as arrays in the form of [x, y].
        All coordinates are given as cartesian coordinates.
        """
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


def __str__(self):
    """
    Returns a string representation of the triangle. The string is formatted as follows:

    Point A: 0.00 0.00
    Point B: 0.00 0.00
    Point C: 0.00 0.00

    """
    return ""
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is my first time using this forum. I thought it was all in the code with comments, so I didn't ask specific questions. I'll do it next time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation and how it could be done. You can to return the string and keep in mind to cast the integers to string.

```
class Triangle():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        """
        Constructor for Vec4
        Expects points as arrays in the form of [x, y].
        All coordinates are given as cartesian coordinates.
        """
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


    def __str__(self):
        """
        Returns a string representation of the triangle. The string is formatted as follows:

        Point A: 0.00 0.00
        Point B: 0.00 0.00
        Point C: 0.00 0.00

        """
        return "Point A: " + str(self.a[0]) + " " + str(self.a[1]) + "\nPoint B: " + str(self.b[0]) + " " + str(self.b[1]) + "\nPoint C: " + str(self.c[0]) + " " + str(self.c[1])

t = Triangle([5,4], [1,2], [7,9])
print(t)
```

Outputs:

```
Point A: 5 4
Point B: 1 2
Point C: 7 9
```

Comment: Please accept the best answer by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers

Answer (score 0):

assuming that a point is a tuple like (1.5, 6.7)

here is the code:

```
class Triangle():
def __init__(self, a, b, c):
    """
    Constructor for Vec4
    Expects points as arrays in the form of [x, y].
    All coordinates are given as cartesian coordinates.
    """
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c


def __str__(self):
    """
    Returns a string representation of the triangle. The string is formatted as follows:

    Point A: 0.00 0.00
    Point B: 0.00 0.00
    Point C: 0.00 0.00

    """
    return f"Point A: {self.a[0]} {self.a[1]}\nPoint B: {self.b[0]} {self.b[1]}\nPoint C: {self.c[0]} {self.c[1]}"
```

you can chech this using:

```
t = Triangle((2.34,4.62), (6.7,8.52), (9.34,3.32))
print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a new method which returns the representation for a single point of the triangle. That way, you can use it inside the `__str__` method, and the code will be less redundant and cleaner.

```
class Triangle():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        """
        Constructor for Vec4
        Expects points as arrays in the form of [x, y].
        All coordinates are given as cartesian coordinates.
        """
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def point_repr(self, p):
        """
        Make a string representation of a point 'p', and return it.

        p: list of the form [x, y].
        """
        coords = "{0} {1}".format(*p)
        # OR
        coords = "{} {}".format(p[0], p[1])
        return coords


    def __str__(self):
        """
        Returns a string representation of the triangle. The string is formatted as follows:

        Point A: 0.00 0.00
        Point B: 0.00 0.00
        Point C: 0.00 0.00

        """

        template = "Point {}: {}"

        a = self.point_repr(self.a)
        b = self.point_repr(self.b)
        c = self.point_repr(self.c)

        point_a = template.format("A", a)
        point_b = template.format("B", b)
        point_c = template.format("C", c)

        formatted = "{}\n{}\n{}".format(point_a, point_b, point_c)

        return formatted
```